# Creating functions, name not defined and passed by reference

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been self-learning python and have gone through the Intro to Python course on Udacity and am currently practicing  python problems on this site [Praticepython.org](http://www.practicepython.org/)

I'm currently at [Exercise 10](http://www.practicepython.org/exercise/2014/04/10/10-list-overlap-comprehensions.html) and have decided to start putting things into a function to make things neater and hopefully more understandable.

However, I've run into a problem.

```
def getlistlen():
    list1len, list2len = raw_input("Please input the lengths of the 2 lists, seperated by a space: ").split()
    list1len = int(list1len)
    list2len = int(list2len)
    print(list1len)
    print(list2len)
    generatelist()


def generatelist():
    print(list1len)
    print(list2len)
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    for i in range(1, list1len+1):
        list1.append(random.randint(1,100))

    for i in range(1, list2len+1):
        list2.append(random.randint(1,100))
    print(list1)
    print(list2)
```

I have tried defining the variables

- list1len
- list2len
- list1
- list2

outside of everything, but if I do that, the values don't change after the functions execute.

I've also tried declaring list1len and list2len under getlistlen() but the function generatelist() cannot retrieve the values for list1len and list2len.

How do I fix this?

From what I understand, variables from outside the functions will only change if what happens inside the function changes them, however, they will not change if they are redeclared inside the function.

Using Python 2.7.12, IDLE IDE.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not simply _pass these lists as an arguments_ to `generatelist()`?

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Since this is a problem of _scope_ indentation matters. _A lot_.

Comment: Has no previous exercise explained how to return and save values from functions?

Comment: Save the input within your function in local variables, then in the end return them and use the function call to assign the values to your variables outside of your function code.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski Are you referring to something like Prakhar Trivedi has suggested?

Comment: You appear to be using python 3 syntax - use of `range()` rather than `xrange()` and the `print()` function.  Yet you say you are using 2.7.  Be careful of that, there are subtle (and not so subtle) differences that will mis-lead you.  If learning python then you would be better starting with python 3.

Comment: @AdventL Tried my solution yet??

Comment: @cdarke I must have referred to the wrong documentation when looking for the print function.

Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi Hi, yes I've tried it.

If in the future I require the use of variables not defined within the function, I will have to add them as parameters when defining the function?

Comment: @AdventL you need to understand the scope of a function and where to define variables in order to get them.

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi It's my first time writing functions out of scratch without referring to any tutorials so I'm not that good with them yet /:

Do you have a link to examples I can read up on?

Comment: @AdventL try this http://www.learnpython.org/

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi Thank you, I will take a look at it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the defined variables into function **generatelist()** in order to use them.
Try this code :

```
def generatelist(list1len,list2len):
    print(list1len)
    print(list2len)
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    for i in range(list1len):
        list1.append(random.randint(1,100))

    for i in range(list2len):
        list2.append(random.randint(1,100))
    print(list1)
    print(list2)


def getlistlen():
    list1len, list2len = raw_input("Please input the lengths of the 2 lists, seperated by a space: ").split()
    list1len = int(list1len)
    list2len = int(list2len)
    print(list1len)
    print(list2len)
    generatelist(list1len,list2len)
```

Firstly define **generatelist()** and then use it into another function in order to calculate list.

Comment: What's wrong with `range(list1len)`?  Or better, use a list comprehension.

Comment: @cdarke I did not correct his code,just showed him the way to pass variables into function.

Comment: @cdarke From the tutorials I've watched, they just use range(start,stop), so I've just followed them. 

From what I understand if i just used range(list1len) it will include 0 which I do not want to include.

Comment: @cdarke

I've changed it to 

list1 = [(random.randint(1,100)) for i in range (0, list1len)]
list2 = [random.randint(1,100)) for i in range (0, list2len)]

to make use of list comprehension. (Hope I'm doing it right)

Comment: The first parameter to `range` defaults to zero.